# How to separate constructor declared explicitly into .h & .cpp files?

Tags: c++

Here is a piece of code which I found in OpenCV tutorial (source https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/core/file_input_output/file_input_output.cpp). Because the code is all in one file I try to separate it into header and cpp. My problem is I cannot find out how to do it correctly not to generate error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int.

```
class MyData
{
public:
MyData() : A(0), X(0), id() {}
explicit MyData(int) : A(97), X(CV_PI), id("mydata1234") // explicit to avoid implicit conversion
{}
void write(FileStorage& fs) const //Write serialization for this class
{
fs << "{" << "A" << A << "X" << X << "id" << id << "}";
}

public: // Data Members
int A;
double X;
string id;
};
```

So this is the part which I am stuck at:

```
MyData() : A(0), X(0), id() {}
explicit MyData(int) : A(97), X(CV_PI), id("mydata1234") // explicit to
```

A declaration (header file) which I tried:

```
class MyData
{
    public: // Data Members
        int A;
        double X;
        std::string id;

        MyData() ;
        explicit MyData(int);

    void write(cv::FileStorage& fs) const;
    void read(const cv::FileNode& node);
};

#endif
```

The thing in .cpp

```
MyData::MyData() : A(0), X(0), id() {}  // this is simple
```

But what next?

```
MyData::MyData(int) : 
    A(97), X(CV_PI), id("mydata1234") {};
MyData::write(cv::FileStorage& fs) const 
{ // ... it will stuck here C4430 
 }
```

using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: What's the purpose of `int` argument in constructor?

Comment: Check the original code for: `//read` and `//write` read #132: `MyData m;` write #77: `MyData m(1);` the number 1 says that we will use a string "mydata1234" during file write operation. While during reading we will read some specific stuff from the file `fs["MyData"] >> m;` line #137(?). As far as I understand the original code. So you can either pass nothing to the constructor or pass int. I don't know exactly why the author written it this way, but I would like to do it as he intended but give it to two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a body for your `write` method outside of the class definition the format is :

```
return-type classname::methodname(parameters)
{
}
```

So in this case:

```
void MyData::write(cv::FileStorage& fs) const 
{ 

}
```

Comment: So you basicly suggest to remove "explicit" from the declaration. Which is not what I wanted.

Comment: @JohnBoe, this is addressing your `write` function, not your explicit constructor

Comment: @JohnBoe No I don't. You need to add `void`. You don't have to add `explicit` to your implementation, only in your declaration. I never said you have to remove it.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was watching incorrect direction. I thought this is with the constructor problem. I fixed it now. Thanks. All guys here are right but I can accept only one answer

Answer (score 1):

```
MyData::write(cv::FileStorage& fs) const 
{ // ... it will stuck here C4430 
 }
```

`C4430` is "missing type specifier".  It's because the `MyData::write()` implementation contains no return type.  Only constructors should omit a return type.  Change it to `void MyData::write(cv::FileStorage& fs) const` to match its declaration.

Answer (score 1):

In your hpp when you are declaring it should be something like this :

```
class Name{
 .....some other functions  ....
void write(cv::FileStorage& fs);
};
```

and in your cpp you need first to include your hpp and then :

```
void Name::write(cv::FileStorage& fs)
{
    .......body...
}
```

So first say the type of the funciton (in this case `void`) then name of the `class` then `::` and then the function name .

hope this helped :)